# Evaluate Match function with variables

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate, excel-match

I would like to use this through VBA -

```
=MATCH("PlanA",A:A,0)
```

with `EVALUATE`.

```
Sub Test()

Dim SectionStartRow As Integer    
Dim planname As String
planname = "PlanA"

SectionStartRow = [MATCH(planname,A:A,0)] 'Error 2029 /// Type mismatch '13

End Sub
```

I've already tried:

```
SectionStartRow = Evaluate("MATCH(planname,A:A,0)") 'Error 2029 /// Type mismatch '13
```

and

```
SectionStartRow = Evaluate("MATCH(" & planname & ",A:A,0)")
```

but nothing seems to work. Please note that `planname` variable is denied by a long set of functions.

Comment: Have you tried using `Application.Worksheetfunction.Match`?

Comment: Yeah, that works, I just thought it would be better to use evaluate instead.

Comment: Can you try the last one with plugging a = sign just before the MATCH?

Comment: Evaluate("=MATCH(" & planname & ",A:A,0)") results the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `planname` needs to be wrapped around string quotes.
The excel equivalent is `=MATCH("PlanA",A:A,0)`, and the string that is passed to `Evaluate` should be identical to that:

```
SectionStartRow = Evaluate("=MATCH( " & Chr(34) & planname & Chr(34) & ",A:A,0)")
```

works OK (tested with Excel 2010)

`Chr(34)` stands for the `"` symbol in ASCII numbering.

Another way to go about it would be to define

```
planname = Chr(34) & "PlanA" & Chr(34)
```

and then do 
    `SectionStartRow = Evaluate("=MATCH( " & planname & ",A:A,0)")`

By the way, I would define `SectionStartRow` as `Long` and not `Integer`, because `Integer`  will throw an error if the matching row is after 32,767.

Note also that the shorthand form of `Evaluate` (that is, the square brackets `[]`) won't work in this case. It works only when [everything inside the brackets is a constant, not a variable](http://academy.excelhero.com/vanilla/index.php?p=/discussion/136/arrays-and-shorthand-notation/p1).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this useful question and struggled with connecting not only the `planname` but also resolve it with a different sheet.

I was confused with the double quotation mark and & symbol from the answer by Ioannis.
`planname = Chr(34) & "PlanA" & Chr(34)`

In my example a version of the below line correctly resolved the first parameter. So only **one** `"& variable &"` worked for me.

`SectionStartRow = Evaluate("=MATCH('Sheet1'!C " & variablename & ",A:A,0)")`